# Identifying overlapping item

Tags: objective-c, image, coordinate-systems

I am writing app in Objective C. I have images dropping down the screen. The other image should catch it. What I want is to identify when the image has been selected.

I was planning to use these lines of code:

```
imgCatcher.frame.origin.x, imgProg1.frame.origin.x
```

within this method:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Is that the x coordinate at the middle of the item or the left most his side?
Any suggestions regarding this task?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x coordinate is the upper left hand corner of the frame. You can use the x and y coordinates together to grab the exact upper lefthand point. I would also maybe just compare the entire frame as a whole (if the images are different sizes). Or when the user touches the image, set some sort of property inside it indicating that it is currently selected.